# How to set a permission to let a SQL server user to access for certain tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I just created two tables and they are named as tblA and tblB. I also created a user(Security/Login) who will be used for a remote insert/update.

What is the best way to permit this user to access for only those two table out of 50 table. I have tried look for the way from (Security/Login) and (Database/Properties). Can I limit it from user account level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a 'grant' statement:

```
grant select on tblA to the_user_name
grant insert on tblA to the_user_name
grant update  on tblA to the_user_name
```

Comment: Does that mean that the user is only allowed to tblA? Do I not have to  deny for other tables?

Comment: I am glad it worked. No, you do not have to deny access to other tables. This is only useful if the user was granted rights inn some other way (say, as a role member) and you want to revoke those rights.

Comment: yup - 'grant select' will work on any view - granting insert and update only make sense if the view is updateable